# relating complex number to real no. using eulers formula.

Tags: complex-numbers

$$e^{i*\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$

for $\theta=\pi/2$

$$e^{i\pi/2}=i$$
raising index by ***-i*** on Lhs and Rhs
$$e^{\pi/2}=i^{-i}$$
does this means **i^(-i)** is real number.

Or am I doing something wrong?

please tell. and sorry for my writing using MathJax.

Comment: To typeset $\pi$, use `\pi`. You can also use `\cos`, etc.

Comment: Why do you think that $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$ when $y,z$ are complex numbers? You either have to give up that rule, or you need to give up the idea that $x^y$ is a single-valued function. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/463902/7933), for example.

Answer (score 2):

This is just one of the values of $i^{-i}$. Notice you can also write something like $e^{i\pi/2+i2n\pi} = i$ and find more values of $i^{-i}$.

---

**Edit**
Since there is a convention for a principal value of exponentiation, your reasoning does give the principal value for $i^{-i}$; still complex exponentiation is generally multi-valued.