# Confusion regarding imaginary numbers

Tags: calculus

So I have

1. $i=e^{i\pi/2}=e^{5×i\pi/2}$
2. If I raise it to the power of $i$,
    $i^i=[e^{i\pi/2}]^i=[e^{5×i\pi/2}]^i$

Hence I have $e^{-\pi/2}=e^{-5\pi/2}$?

Can someone please tell me what I did wrong in my steps?

Comment: This comes up quite often here. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/463902/7933)

Answer (score 0):

You found a valid argument to conclude that "raising to the power of $i$" is not well defined in complex numbers. In fact powers in the complex numbers are defined as
$$a^b = e^{b \log a} = \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n!}(b \log a)^n$$

where $b$ is a complex number, and $a$ is a positive real number.

Answer (score 0):

Expressions like this typically are multivalued. This arises directly from the ambiguity of the angle chosen in polar coordinates. There are countably infinitely many distinct values of $i^i$; for each integer $k$ we have a possible value:

$$i^i = e^{i\log i} = e^{i\cdot(\frac{\pi i}{2} - 2k\pi i)}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi} = \boxed{e^{(4k-1)\pi}}$$

Your values come from taking $k=0$ and $k=-1$ in my expression. Note that you have an error in one of these (you should have written $e^{-\pi/2}$, not $e^{\pi/2}$).

The ordinary laws of exponents have to be handled with care when the exponents are complex, because you are typically talking about a family of values, not a single value. The upshot is usually that there is *at least one* of the values that satisfies the desired equation, but they don't usually all satisfy it.